# React Native form ref empty

Tags: forms, react-native

I have a form `productDetails` and I want to access the value of this form once the user clicks the button `Post Your Ad`.

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to access the value of the form. The error is `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.refs.productDetails.getValue')`

I think reason why I am getting this error is because `this.refs` is empty. But I dont know why it is empty.

Help is much appreciated.

```
    renderScene(route, navigator) {
return (
   <View style={styles.body}>
    <Form ref="form">
      <Text style={{color:'black'}}>Add Photos</Text>
      <View style={styles.viewRow}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectPhoto.bind(this,0)}>
          <View style={{width: 100,marginLeft:5, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'skyblue', marginTop:5}}>
            { arr[0] == null ? <Text></Text> :
              <Image style={styles.selectedImage} source={arr[0]} />
            }
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectPhoto.bind(this,1)}>
            <View style={{width: 100,marginLeft:5, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'skyblue',marginTop:5}}>
              { 
                arr[1] == null ? <Text></Text> :
                <Image style={styles.selectedImage} source={arr[1]} />
              }
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

        <View style={styles.viewRow}>
        <View style={styles.viewColumn}>

          <Text style={{color:'black'}} >Select Category</Text>
          <TextInput type="TextInput" name="category"
            style={styles.textInputMedium}/>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.viewColumn}>
          <Text style={{color:'black'}}>Price</Text>
          <TextInput type="TextInput" name="price"
            placeholder='NRs.'
            style={styles.textinputSmall}/>
        </View>  
      </View>
      <View style={styles.viewColumn}>
          <Text style={{color:'black'}}>Title</Text>
            <TextInput type="TextInput" name="title"
            placeholder='Add Title'
            style={{height: 40,width:305, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}/>
       </View> 
      <View style={styles.viewColumn}>
        <Text style={{color:'black'}}>Description</Text>
        <TextInput type="TextInput" name="description"
          placeholder='Add Description'
          style={styles.textInputBig}/>
      </View>  
    </Form>
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.submit}
        onPress={this.gotoNext.bind(this)}>
      <Text style={styles.submitText}>Post Your Ad</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>

);
}
```

Function called on button press

```
gotoNext() {
console.log(this.refs);//this is empty
console.log(this.refs.productDetails.getValue());//this throws error
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive googling I've found the solution to this problem.
The problem was I was using a navigator so to access the ref of my form I had to access it through the ref of the navigator.

```
gotoNext() {
   var formObject = this.refs.navigator.refs.form.getValues();
}
```